# Draggable not working with AJAX request - Angular

Tags: ajax, angular, draggable

I would like to implement elements with a draggable property. You get what you wanted in part. I have several blocks that are built from the response of a web-service.

Use ng-repeat to represent the elements on the screen:

```
<div class = "declareContainer" ng-repeat = "item in group">
   <!-- My Draggable Boxes -->
  <div id="{{$index}}" title="{{$index}}" class="col-lg-6" style=" border radius: 15px; padding: 1%; ">
 </div>
```

The loop is controlled by "group" object, however it is obtained by AJAX:

```
  $Http.get (path + "getgroup"). Then (function (response) {
     $ Scope.group = response.data;
    }, Function (error) {

  });
```

I use the following excerpt in my controller to apply a draggable property to the elements that are in the declareContainer div:

```
  Angular.element (document) .ready (function () {
     $ (".declareContainer"). Draggable ();
  });
```

Elements are drawn normally, but lose a draggable property.

I ran tests and noticed that when defining the group object in static or exploit code (ng-repat already gets as object of the object during the construction of the app).
I tried to initialize "group" as null for the loop not to`enter code here` run while a response is not, but still giving the same problem.

Does anyone know of any way to solve this problem?